# Required_if laravel request Id 's name must be equal to value-Validation

Tags: laravel

In my Project I want to perform some validations

```
 public function rules()
{
    return [
        'first_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'last_name' => 'string|max:255',
        'email' => 'email|max:255|required_without:phone|unique:users',
        'phone' => 'string|max:255|required_without:email|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:8',
        'school_id' => 'required|exists:schools,id',
        'city' => 'required|string',
        'class_id' => 'required|exists:klasses,id',
        'school_name'=>'required_if://here i need validation
    ];
}
```

Here the `school_id` is holding the `id` of the school.. so in my case, If the user passed the `id` of a school whose having `name` **Others** I want to set the school_name as mandatory in the request how do I can achieve this?..

Answer (score 0):

To make `school_name` mandatory when `school_id` is empty, you can simply use the [`required_if`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-required-if) rule with the input.

```php
Rule::requiredIf(function () {
    return empty($this->input('school_id'));
}
```

It will check if there's input for the `school_id`, and if there's not, then the `school_name` is required.